# click a hyperlink with javascript - href="#"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm new to Javascript.

I would like to click a hyperlink with Javascript.

the html looks like this:

```
<a id="random563e035c2b9149" class="btn" href="#">Launch PDF editor...</a>
```

the id changes every time I refresh the page, so I can't use it.

how do I click this hyperlink with javascript?

( if it helps, this is the div this hyperlink is in:

```
<div class="visibleifjs" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1446906385088_829"><a id="random563e0a0eede6f9" class="btn" href="#">Launch PDF editor...</a><div class="assignfeedback_editpdf_unsavedchanges warning">Unsaved changes</div></div>
```

)

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but it's ugly... hope someone has a better idea.

luckily there are only three buttons ('btn' class) on this page, so the button I want to push was easy to find (but in other cases, if there are a million button on this page it wouldn't be so easy to find the right one...)

in my case, my button is the first button, so this works:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

> the id changes every time I refresh the page, so I can't use it.

`id` appear to begin with string `"random"` ? , followed by random integers ?

Try selecting `a` having `id` beginning with `"random"` , having `class` `btn` ; calling `.click()` on `DOM` element

```
$("a[id^=random][class=btn]")[0].click()
```

Comment: maybe I'm not using this code right, when I put it in my console it says: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM241:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM225:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM225:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM225:664

Answer (score 0):

you can use class asigned to it:

```
 $(".btn").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).html());

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id of the parent div stays the same.

```
$('#yui_3_17_2_2_1446906385088_829 a').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

Comment: how do you know witch Ids stay the same?